# Capture YUVY(YUY2) Image from webcam

Tags: opencv, webcam, rgb, yuv, v4l2

I have tech-com web-cam which only support YUVY(YUY 4:2:2) image format. I am using ubuntu 32 bit OS. I want to display image and store it but i am struggling with YUVY to RGB conversion. I have written a code to get frame from web-cam using V4l2 but unable to display. i want easy way to convert yuvy image so i display and save that image on PC.

I tried many examples but only got vertical green lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could try OpenCV's `VideoCapture`. It supports YUV format. Install OpenCV and also install `libv4l2` using `apt-get`.

```
VideoCapture cap = VideoCapture(-1);
Mat img = cap.read();
imwrite("image.jpg", img);
```

You can even use OpenCV with Python.